# IF Column F = TEXT THEN change Column G

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sure this is very simple but I'm having a difficult time getting it right.
Basically, if Column F is equal to a text string, then Column G should show another text string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is like this:

```
     Col F    Col G
1    Black
2    White
3    Black
4
5    White
```

Your formula in Col G should be something like:

```
=IF(F1 = "Black", "Yes", IF(F1 = "White", "No", If(F1 = "", "", "")))
```

Using this formula would give you:

```
     Col F    Col G
1    Black     Yes
2    White     No
3    Black     Yes
4
5    White     No
```

Comment: So I just continue using the FALSE part of the formula to include the next Col F option. Meaning if I had about 10 choices in F, I would have probably 10 end parenthesis at the end, correct?

Answer (score 2):

In your cell in column G:
`=IF(F1="some_value","text_to_display","nothing?")`